# Is there a way to use `unknown` for a constrained type parameter in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, templates, constraints

Is there a way to use `unknown` as a placeholder for constrained type parameters in function signatures in TypeScript?

Suppose I have a class that has an *unconstrained* type parameter `T`:

```
class MyClass<T> {
}
```

Then I can write a function that takes an instance of this class and uses `unknown` as the type parameter:

```
function foo(instance: MyClass<unknown>): void {
  console.log(instance);
}
```

In contrast, suppose the class had a *constrained* type parameter `T`:

```
class MyClass<T extends Record<string, any>> {
}
```

In this case, the function `foo()` as defined above no longer compiles, but rather produces this compilation error:

```
Type 'unknown' does not satisfy the constraint 'Record<string, any>'.
```

To work around this, I write the function with explicit type parameters:

```
function foo<T extends Record<string, any>>(instance: MyClass<T>): void {
  console.log(instance);
}
```

This is, however, inconvenient, and inconsistent with other classes whose type parameter(s) are *not* constrained, for which `unknown` works perfectly and perfectly conveys the semantics. Moreover, to me it *feels* like since you have to cast `unknown` to something more specific before doing anything useful with it anyways that this idiom should be allowed by the compiler.

I tried a searching the Internet for ideas and different permutations of the function signature. I was expecting to find a "easy" way to "ignore" the type parameter if the function's implementation did not care what the actual type was; however, I couldn't find one.

Here is a relevant TypeScript Playground link: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBUAsEsGdQMYBsCGt6TaFA7UB9AVxwQHsdYAXFaHAUwBN9RKBPABztHZQCcUAtnUp1eoAAbhxAOgCwAKGRp4AVRLkq-Wo3AAecAD5QAbwUBfBQpCgAkolygA7r2gjsoAGbEElaORaYlKCEsHTw4sQA1jikjjjinqRilJBcbJzcfILConLy1lBwoEUhdF5IoABGdAgopQFcXiS+-gykYaAxQQIokVy4rMGhoKQeDSwcdFZgPPxCIrwA5PDpdHlNPn54HqSkamQUlFr0DAAUtFS4CHQAXKD7Gkc0J3pRMXEGAJR3AG6k0AwTApQIgNKQkGskKQAObnQ5XOifADc5ks+TANjwByeVAANAEikp0KBMPAUAQDppnoxmKtMnMcmJJDIFET4ABhR7HRj6UB0AAeIhwDHgACUakkGLpNLRofiBgYjKZ5BZ5NMIDB4EVHIFbARHLhKLTSE4XCJ8bBaNdxhsWng2h0uqAen1sDhWOr6qNxnTZtkFssJpwkSTYnQfqJ8a5PDQkCsTWQBOxoBCnK5IOqUlxRLwkndwJNQIs3rEcItQA74E7YChfLAPIMs6DDscgotjGZFutvHbEqROS3qWcLtQSLdQAOqdopSWPt9QH8AUD5CDKeDITC4Zcx8jUWr0RqitrdXZ8JgI8bTa4uCO6ChAd6QrKJLP4viddAEJA+fz2EhP64SAegesCcAg0AeB0Ta+lk8yiG6gJNomyYQmIjgphUtCQckqSgrwvA1EEzIogekBhhGvBRkEkF0HGwQ4PQ1zoHwKaDBRlSkMMuCAlaGhwEKQToSkiCoOgUGBOqmDsJweCUCa55cEQ6iDtOtKFn6cG8LA3bNFsVR8JOTzTryApCiKoDimQvBSjKOBym6rCKluo7XHchnclKhjzougLKquYIQtIUKwiOCK7iqChAA

Comment: Are you looking for `class MyClass<T = unkown> {}` ?

Comment: FYI, An "unconstrained" generic type parameters is implicitly constrained by `unknown`. `Type A<T> = T`  and `Type A<T extends unknown> = T` are _perfectly_ identical types in every way.

Comment: In my specific case I need the type parameter to be constrained to objects. So using `MyClass<T = unknown>` doesn't work for me, as that would allow primitive types like `number` and `string`. I've updated my question to use `Record<string, any>` rather than `{}` to be more clear, and also added a TypeScript Playground link.

Comment: There's no way to automatically propagate type parameter constraints, and you certainly can't just ignore the issue and say `unknown` should be assignable to `object` for the purposes of the constraint (that is identical to someone making an actual error, from the type system point of view).  Whenever you want to "ignore" some type safety feature you can use `any` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w2vAbw).  Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Actually, the `any` type parameter does indeed work; however, it then makes it all too easy to accidentally access that type parameter and the compiler will allow it without doing any validation (the nature of `any`). The benefit of using `unknown` would be that if the type parameter was used then the compiler would force me to explicitly cast it. I'm looking for that `unknown` behavior of forcing me to cast.

Comment: It's safe to say that what you're trying to accomplish with `unknown` it's not possible.  The `unknown` type is the top type (universal supertype) in TS, and has no other meaning (in particular, it does not mean "the widest type that wouldn't cause an error in the current context"). Unconstrained type parameters are implicitly constrained to `unknown`, which is why you can use `unknown` in such situations. Otherwise you need to explicitly constrain things yourself. It might be inconvenient but it's not inconsistent. Do you want to see an answer saying this or am I missing something?